# How to retrieving variable value in C++ if you know the variable address

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, memory-management

Greetings,

I have recently started to code in **C++** and have come across a problem to which I was unable to find the answer, so I thought maybe somebody else might know the answer.

**Is it possible to retrieve a variable value from another program if you know a variable address?** Imagine that I have a memory address displayed in a program, something like: **0x7fff5fbff758** and I would like (in my own program which is not related to the first one) to get the ***value*** stored in that memory address.

Is that possible? If so, could somebody please explain me how.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use Nawaz's answer although be careful what you're doing reading from memory locations or even worse writing to them without having some actual reference other than memory location as they tend to change if your code changes.

Comment: [Ask the goal, not the step](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). What makes you think you need to do this?

Comment: I edited to make it clear that this question is about reading across process boundaries, as there was some confusion about that in the answers.

Comment: It's not fair to decrement the question simply because of your misunderstanding.

Comment: Its perfectly fair, because he still didn't manage to ask the question in way where it could be answered even in the second try - the information what OS he is using is still missing. See how you are trying to guess what he wants to do in your own answer.

Comment: That was clear that he wanted to know if it is possible to pass a variable "by address" between two programs...

Comment: And the fact that a few SO members didn't get the right answer prove that it is a good question to ask.

Comment: To be fair, I don't think he knew enough about what he was asking to know that what OS he is using mattered. Its a reasonable question in a general sense.

Comment: Nawaz: the question was general to the C++, not the OS in question as I was hoping to get a response about a general way to do it, on any OS. But if you really want to know my OS, I use Windows XP.

Comment: @John: It's not possible on "any" OS because the implementation of processes and address spaces is solely *dependent* on the OS. C++ has no concept of an OS, or processes, or virtual memory, etc. You *must* use OS-specific functionality. Also, you still haven't specified why you think you need to do this.

Comment: Because I need to get a variable value from one program to use it in mine, so I thought it would be the easiest way. As for the OS, thanks to be honest I didn't expect the memory addresses to vary between OS' for the same program.

Comment: @Ubiquite: Does no one read tooltips? Specifically, the "downvote" button says "This question is unclear or not useful". Questions that don't make sense are perfect candidates for downvotes. If you understood it, please feel free to edit the question to help out others who may not. And you can certainly upvote the question yourself, if you feel that it *is* clear and useful (coincidentally, the tooltip on the "upvote" button).

Comment: @Cody Gray the problem is that nawaz probably down vote the question because he was upset to get wrong, not because it was truly unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On today operating systems, the programs handle virtual addresses, not physical ones. Shortly, a specific address for one programs will not point to the same physical location for other programs.

To do what you want on modern operating systems, you can, for instance, set up a shared memory location.

But there is a lot of easier way to pass a value from one program to another.

If you are just wondering that out of curiosity, that's a good question, you can look at what "virtual memory" is.

Comment: You can actually read a mem location of a process from a different process without shared memory etc. by doing it the same way as debuggers do ("tracing").

Comment: I think debuggers need "debug information", obtained with the option -g with gcc, for instance.

Comment: @Ubuiquité The "debug information" is for the symbolic addressing.  If you have the actual address, you can read it regardless.  But it's necessarily that simple, and it varies a lot between platforms.

Answer (score 3):

C++ has no comment on this, one way or the other.  It depends entirely on the platform on which your program is running.  If you're using Windows, for example, you can use the ReadProcessMemory() function to read the memory of another process (assuming you have adequate permissions).

Note that modern operating systems are designed to protect processes from interfering with each other.  One of the ways they do this is by giving each process its own address space.  Processes can't access memory outside this space without using special APIs.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but it is OS-specific (there is no common C support for it). In general, your second program needs to have the permission that debugger has, and use the same kind of OS calls that a debugger uses.

Comment: Don't most modern general-purpose OSes use different virtual memory spaces for different processes? If so, then this is actually *not* possible (unless the OP is running on an RTOS or an Amiga or something).

Comment: Hmmm. Reading the rest of your answer, I guess using the debugger API you could do it. Not exactly the cleanest method of IPC though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This obsolete, because the question has changed.

If you know the type of the variable, its possible.

For an int variable, you need to insert lines like

```
int* addr = (int*)0x7fff5fbff758;
std::cout << *addr << std::endl;
```

somewhere in the affected program.

Accessing the variable from a different program is generally not easily done in a modern operating system, each process has it's own address space so the same address in different processes may map to different physical memory location.

It depends on the OS, for example in linux you need to trace a process if you want to do it from a different process, see [man ptrace](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace). You can read the data in this case with PTRACE_PEEKDATA.

Comment: On Windows you just call ReadProcessMemory().

Answer (score 0):

On most modern general-purpose OSes (Windows, Linux, etc), **you cannot do that**. Different programs run in different processes, and each process has its very own memory space. Address 0x7fff5fbff758 in one probably points to a very different place in RAM than address 0x7fff5fbff758 in another (if that address even exists in the other).

This is why modern OSes have interprocess communications mechanisims, like pipes, shared memory, [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model), etc.